# Why is /wp-json issue coming up on Google indexing?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, search, json-ld

Google is currently trying to index our domain (`example.com/wp-json`) and coming up with a 5xx error.

In my perspective, `wp-json` is the root domain of our REST API

It looks like our REST API is running out of memory whilst Google is trying to access it.

We did change our servers last month. But this issue only surfaced recently.

Should I exclude this page from indexing?

Comment: I see no reason why you would want google to index it.

Comment: Is `/wp-json` actually appearing in search results, or is the problem just related to Googlebot hitting it while crawling?

Comment: It is Googlebot hitting it while crawling

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your wording is wrong. What do you call domain, is in fact a path or a folder  - `example.com/wp-json`.

To your situation: Deindexing the folder wouldn't help you to get rid of the running out of memory, because the bot will still come and penetrate.

I would rather block the crawling of the folder, to prevent its reading by the bot. The blocking rule for your robots.txt would be

```
Disallow: /wp-json
```

With this rule you block crawling of `/wp-json`, `wp-json/` and everything placed inside. Explaination by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/robots/robots_txt#url-matching-based-on-path-values).